# Aggregate (AVG) of RunningValue outside of group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have the following values that are calculated using the RunningValue() function.

[image: Data]

This is the Expression used.

```
=RunningValue(Math.Abs(SUM(Fields!paid_amount.Value)/fields!adv_amt.value), Sum, "PercentageFunded")
```

I need to create an average for these values by row but I've been unsuccessful. How do I create an aggregate of RunningValue outside of the group?

Comment: I've tried AVG(RunningValue()) but I get an error. AVG(SUM()) also does not return the correct values.

Comment: You are trying to populate the "Average" column in your screenshot, correct?   In that case, you could try averaging the ReportItem values in each row.